# Add a property to a class instance

Tags: php, class

Let I've a class

```
class MyClass{
    //class implementation
}
```

I want to add the following method to this class:

```
public function addProperty($property){
    //This method will be set a property of a current MyClass instance with the name **property** and the value **$property**
}
```

Any idea to implement this method?

Answer (score 1):

> This method will be set a property of a current MyClass instance with the name **property** and the value **$property**

Its very basic, do:

```
public function addProperty($property){
  $this->property=$property;    // declare it as well
}
```

Or do you mean **property** as just a placeholder? you could then do

```
  $this->{$property}=$property;
```

Comment: How does `{$property}` resolving?

Comment: See Variable Variables Example 1: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: +1. According to the comment `$this->property=$property;` should be the correct answer

Comment: @Sal00m It's not correct. Because $this->property=$property; will be initialize a filed with the name `property`, but I want to initialize a field with the variable name.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv So your comment its not correct, my solution or the second one from HankyPanky should be fine, check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addProperty($property){
    $this->{$property} = $property;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write that method in that class, create one object for that class. And where you want to use that method, just call that method by use of that object

`$obj = new MyClass;
$return = $obj->addProperty();`

in that method if you want to use property, writ down like wise

```
public function addProperty($property){
    $this->property = $property;
}
```

it will gives you the property value